# jquery how to do transition like css?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[jquery transition](https://jsfiddle.net/0zu0ybzv/268/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('#nav').addClass('shrink', 1000);      
        }
        else {
        $('#nav').removeClass('shrink', 1000);
        }
      });

});
```

I am trying to make the jquery transition just like the css transition. When you scroll down the transition will happen.

[css transition: transition is in css. transition: all ease 0.5s](https://jsfiddle.net/0zu0ybzv/269/)

Comment: Try using: $("#nav").css('shrink', 1000);

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You should select the logo element as well in the javascript file and add the following:

```
$('#logo').addClass('shrink', 500);
$('#logo').removeClass('shrink', 500);
```

And instead of `#nav.shrink #logo` you should use `#logo.shrink` in your css file.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zu0ybzv/272/)